# Checking For Element Position in Array and Printing New Line After Checking

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

So I've written this code and it works until I try implemented a part of my second for loop where I try to print a new line. It is suppose to print a new line after the 8th element being printed. Any help appreciated.

```
// Construct a for loop that runs backwards through the array,
// starting at the last element and ending at the first.

 for (int i = arraySize; i > 0; i--) {

    // Inside this for loop, print the ith element of the array
    // and a tab, with NO newline characters.
    cout << newArray[i-1] << "  ";

    // If this element is the 8th one on its line, print a
    // newline character to advance to the next line.
    // Also inside this for loop, add the value of the ith
    // element to the current value of the double for the sum
    // of elements.

    //ISSUE IS HERE
    if (newArray[i-8] = newArray[7]) {
        cout << "\n";
    }

    sumOfElements += newArray[i-1];

}
```

I've only pasted the for loop that has the issue, I don't believe any other information is necessary as I know it works up until this point.

Answer (score 2):

You want comparison (`==`) not assignment (`=`). But in any case this

```
if (newArray[i-8] = newArray[7]) {
    cout << "\n";
}
```

is wrong. For `i < 8` you will access negative indices, which is out-of-bounds. To check if you are printing the 8th element from the array you only need to look at the index:

```
if (i == 7) {
    cout << "\n";
}
```

It you rather want to put a new line after 8 elements have been printed then it is

```
if (i == arraySize-7) {
    cout << "\n";
}
```

If instead you want to put a new line after each 8 elements that have been printed then it is

```
if ( (i - arraySize - 1)%8 == 0) {
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: So i get that, thanks for helping with that small mistake. But in this case, i is counting down. Would that not affect where it would print a new line?

Comment: @Lonely should the new line appear after the 8th array element or in the 8th iteration? Those are not the same when you count backwards, and in the question you say it is the first

Comment: Yeah, it is suppose to appear after the 8th element has been printed

Comment: so i have checked with i==7, and it does the new line prematurely

Comment: @Lonely the 8th element in the array or the 8th element that gets printed? They are not the same

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, then in this case, after the 8th element gets printed. Not the 8th element in the array.

Comment: However, what if I got the the 16th element being printed?

Comment: @Lonely you want a new line after printing every 8th element?

Comment: Yes, sorry that I didn't make that clear earlier, but you've helped my understanding a lot.

Comment: I can not thank you enough, I have a terrible grasp on the modulus usage. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Lonely you can do it by experimenting, write a loop that only counts down, but the modulo inside and see what is the output, thats what I did. Btw I am not sure about `i == arraySize-8` being correct, it might be off by one

Comment: I've been actively testing the code as you were helping. It works the way it should. And yes, your previous i == arraySize - 8 was incorrect, it should have been i == arraySize - 7